# Smoothing or averaging plots to better represent trends and their variations

Tags: matplotlib, plotting, python-3.x

My picture looks like this. It shows some percent variation but, due to fluctuations, curves are not very smooth at all.

[image]

I would like to draw a smoother image, without altering too much the data (it is okay if the graph is not a perfect representation of the data).
I am using matplotlib to draw the data, and my code looks like this:

```
x = df["Value"].shift(period)+1
y = 100*df["Value"].diff(period)/(period*x)
```

Basically, it draws the variation from the total over a period. What is the suggested way to alter the points (possibly drawing them alongside) the original data, so that the graphs do not look so jagged?

I tried just drawing every other third point, doing:

```
w = x[2::3]
z = y[2::3]
```

but I am sure there are better ways to do this. Again, this is for a nice representation only and I am mostly interested in showing a trend or any variation of it, not in showing the exact data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take averages piecewise. Ideally, is like sliding a window of size k on the trend, taking the average of these points (it could be 3 or 5, for example).

Alternatively, you can use exponential smoothing functions, such as [savgol filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) available in `scipy`, LOESS smoothing, or Holt-Winters smoothing. The `statsmodels.tsa` submodule made many smoothing techniques available.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to use the savgol filter. It was very easy to implement.

Comment: You're right! I always use Savgol when I'm in a hurry